# CSS Centre list items in a grid

Tags: html, css, css-float

Firstly my CSS skills are... a work in progress.  But I have got so far in as to successfully have a bunch of list items arranged in a grid. http://jsfiddle.net/ashanova/Y4SR3/2/

What I'd like to do now is centre the list items.  I have tried to replace `float` with `inline` but it causes the `width` and `height` of each item to collapse.   I would also like to  centre the text horizontally and vertically within each list item as well, ideally ellipsisizing (not a word) overflow text.   As one last specification I would like to only modify CSS to the `ul` and its children if thats possible.

Comment: " I would like to only modify CSS to the ul and its children if thats possible." - Yes, just edit the CSS.

Comment: @Diodeus Ha, yes I would assume editing the CSS would be key to this solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the language gets a little unclear when you're dealing with multiple parent and child elements, and centering (/middling) on 2 axes, I think that if the other answers aren't what you're looking for, you might actually want `display: table-cell`.

Check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/crowjonah/Y4SR3/15/).

If you give your `li` elements `display: table-cell`, `text-align: center` and `vertical-align: middle`, I think the text will arrange itself appropriately. Unfortunately, `table-cell`  elements don't accept margin, so I added a 10px border instead.

In order to accomplish truncation of text that overflows and the insertion of an ellipse, you'll need to use some kind of javascript.

**UPDATE**

Having learned more about what you're after through the many other answers and comments, I've come up with a better solution here: http://jsfiddle.net/crowjonah/jx8sD/

What you need to do is insert `<a class="list-item">` tags inside the `li` elements, and use this CSS:

```
.tile li {
    background-color: white;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.tile li a.list-item{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 75px;
    text-align: center;
    width:75px;

}
```

Comment: thats a good start, but like I just said to Diodeus "I'd like the list items to spill over to the next line if there are too many, your solution seems to cause each element to re-adjust its width to squeeze them all into one line" any idea how i could incorporate that?

Answer (score 0):

`Text-align: center` will align your list items to the center. `Vertical-align: text-top` will align items to the center vertically.

Comment: sorry i dont want the list items centred vertically just horizontally.  Its just the text that I want vertically aligned

Comment: Those two bits of CSS should do what you want, just apply them to the appropriate elements.

Comment: It works on the horizontal but not vertical text in the jsfiddle.  It also doesn't centre the actual list items

Answer (score 0):

`vetical-align` will not actually do the job in this case.  I wish it were that simple.

This aricle will give you some insight into the problem and will help you solve it:

[Understanding vertical-align, or "How (Not) To Vertically Center Content"](http://phrogz.net/CSS/vertical-align/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you want. Borders on inline-block items are a pain, so I'm using a border to make it look right.

```
.tile li {
    background-color: white;
    display:inline-block;
    border: 10px solid red;
    width: 75px;
    height: 75px;
    text-align:center;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: that looks a lot better! I'd still like the list items to spill over to the next line if there are too many, your solution seems to cause each element to re-adjust its width to squeeze them all into one line

Comment: If you're aiming at making a menu, you will need to add an A-tag in each item. This will give you a little more flexibility in how CSS is applied. Move your LI styles to the A-tag (except for float) and you can tweak it bit from there.

Comment: Its a Dashbaord/metro style layout so each list item is a hyperlink

Comment: Ok, give that a spin and post a new question if it's not working out.